# (Impossible) HtmlAgilityPack not found in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, html-agility-pack

*I have a problem with the HtmlAgilityPack...*
 I have correctly imported the pack in Visual Studio (References > Manage NuGet Packages > Browse, and just installed the package)
In Unity I get this error:

> Assets/Scripts/Searcher.cs(13,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HtmlAgilityPack' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I didn't forgot two add `using HtmlAgilityPack;` in my script

**Using ? :**
 - Unity 2017.2.1f1
 - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
 - HtmlAgilityPack 1.6.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a similar question over on [Unity Answers](https://answers.unity.com/questions/631546/using-a-nuget-package-jsonnet.html):

> Unity itself is incapable of handling Nuget packages, they're more of a VS thing. But as long as the assembly targets .NET 2.0 you should be able to use the .dll in Unity without issue

I can't find any information on what version of .NET that HtmlAgilityPack targets, but my guess is that it *isn't* the same as what Unity uses. By default Unity 2017 uses the .NET 3.5 runtime with an option to switch to the experimental 4.6 runtime.

The best compatibility will be with both targetting the same version, but in the case of it differing, Unity will need to be *newer* as if the dll uses features added by (say) .NET 4.6 and Unity's set to use .NET 3.5, Unity won't be able to handle those calls.

Try changing to the .NET 4.6 experimental runtime and seeing if that works.

Under Edit -> Project -> Player:

[image: Settings]

Comment: Hum.... How to do ? I want to use HtmlAgilityPack for parsing the HTML, do you know an other way to do that ? (not to difficult i'm not a professional xD)

Comment: *`Try changing to the .NET 4.6 experimental runtime and seeing if that works.`* Did you try that? Did it not work?

Comment: I don't know how to do that :(

Comment: @Aiixu Added a picture to my answer

Comment: ? > Added a picture to my answer ? I translated with Google Translate, and I don't understand too :o

Comment: @Aiixu Sorry it's in Edit -> Project -> Player. Or you can get to it by going to File -> Build then clicking the Build Settings button. The depicted setting is in under the "Other Settings" collapsible section.

Comment: Don't worry ^^ Thanks ! I try it NOW :)

Comment: Ok, I think that Unity disable the HtmlAgilityPack because when I open the script, the pack is missing :o. With an VS solution, there isn't any probleme >.< I think there isn't any solution :o

Comment: @Aiixu That's a shame :\

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this was marked impossible. You can do this by simply dropping HTMLAgilityPack.dll into Unity.  Unity will recognize the library and make it available in VS2017.

[Here's what it looks like in Unity when imported correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5784C.png)

I am on (Experimental .Net 4.6), but I doubt that makes a difference.

Comment: As I said in my answer, it was based on information I was able to find. I've never messed with NuGet myself (in or out of Unity).

Comment: Yes, the process was just incorrect, I added this answer because at the end of the thread it looked like Aixu just gave up. He was just going about adding HTMLAgilityPack in completely the wrong way.