# How to get text displayed in a webpage as string

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, html

I got a website page running html script that shows a clock-ticks value which updates every half a second. This is the only content in this page.

I would like to get the value that is shown on this page, as I run my code.
Everything I tried until now just gave me my html code that I made in order to show the clock-ticks value.

Because I'm using Unity, I'm trying to do that without 3rd party tools.

How can I do that?

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48191309/impossible-htmlagilitypack-not-found-in-unity While you can't use teh NuGet package manager, it should still be possible to add a reference to HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: If you dont want to use anything 3rd party, how about you parse the html code for the value you want?

Comment: Although I've managed to implement HtmlAgilityPack to Unity, I'm keep failing to get the value, guessing because it's a dynamic (ticks that are changing every half a second).